# clases cambiar el valor de un elemento dentro del constructor de una clase

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente clase, y me estoy volviendo loco intentando cambiarle el valor a uno de los items que está dentro del constructor, no sé si llamarles parámetros, porque leyendo MDN wen docs, no me quedó muy claro cuál sería el nombre correcto para dichos items.

Tengo la siguiente clase

```js
class Player{
  constructor(cutY, cutX, y, x){
  this.cutY = cutY
  this.cutX = cutX
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.gunsPoint
  this.contadorPlayer1 = 0
  this.contadorPlayer2 = 0
  this.dataPlayer
  this.dataCounter
  this.activePlayer
  }
```

Lo que quiero, es cambiar el valor de `this.contadorPlayer1` estando dentro de la propia clase. No quiero aumentar el valor de `this.contadorPlayer1` de un en uno con ++ pre y post. Lo que quiero es cambiar el valor he introducir un valor x pero desde dentro de la propia clase, ya que tengo una función que me ayuda a contar los pasos de cada jugador y cada x pasos, cambiar de turno.

Los jugadores están instanciados y puedo moverlos, detectar armas en el tablero, detectar la posición del contrario y detectar los obstaculos del mapa, pero no no consigo modificar el valor del `this.contadorPlayer1`

Lo he intentado con una función dentro de la propia clase, pero no funciona.

Answer (score 4):

Primero.

- El constructor es el método que se va a iniciar primero una vez que la clase sea inicializada en una instancia
- Segundo dentro del constructor tienes una serie de propiedades que inicializas
- Entonces requieres de un método que tome esa propiedad y la aumente en 1
- Posterior cuando **instancias** la clase deberás llamar varias veces a dicho método para aumentar su valor original, siguiendo la sintaxis de **`objeto.metodo()`**
- Preferentemente **no hagas operaciones de impresión de valores dentro del contexto de la clase**, en su lugar **solo retornalos**

Código

```
class Player{
  constructor(cutY, cutX, y, x){
  this.cutY = cutY
  this.cutX = cutX
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.gunsPoint
  this.contadorPlayer1 = 0
  this.contadorPlayer2 = 0
  this.dataPlayer
  this.dataCounter
  this.activePlayer
  }

  aumentaPlayer1() {
    return this.contadorPlayer1++
  }
}

const Objeto = new Player;
console.log(Objeto.aumentaPlayer1())
console.log(Objeto.aumentaPlayer1())
console.log(Objeto.aumentaPlayer1())
```

Dando como resultado

```
0
1
2
```

**EDICIÓN**

Para pedir un valor y asignarselo a tu propiedad `contadorPlayer1` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Al método pásale un argumento que tendrá para fines prácticos `contador`
- Por dentro del método hacemos un `return` de la propiedad `contadorPlayer1` y le sumamos el valor dinámico que representa el parámetro `contador`
- Como ahora ese método espera un valor en su pareja de pantesis, cuando el objeto accede al método debemos pasarle por ejemplo un número

Quedando así:

```
class Player{
  constructor(cutY, cutX, y, x){
    this.contadorPlayer1 = 0
    this.contadorPlayer2 = 0
  }

  aumentaPlayer1(contador) {
    return this.contadorPlayer1 += contador
  }
}

const Objeto = new Player;
console.log(Objeto.aumentaPlayer1(21))
console.log(Objeto.aumentaPlayer1(33))
console.log(Objeto.aumentaPlayer1(12))
```

Comment: Gracias. 

Lo que pasa es que no quiero aumentar de un en uno, eso ya lo hago, lo que quiero, es introducir un valor x.

Comment: @Sargentogato deja modifico la respuesta entonces

Comment: Gracias de nuevo. Probe algo similar, no obstante, si paso un valor desde fuera, tengo que forzosamente hacerlo con cada click del teclado que mueve al jugador activo, lo malo de ello, es que si se encuentra un obstáculo, no discrimina el click y lo toma en cuenta, obligándome a hacer otra función que que tenga en cuenta cuando choca con un obstáculo y dejarla fuera, cuando lo que intento, es hacer que todo se haga dentro de la clase.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien  quieres modificar contadorPlayer1 de una instancia de la clase en la misma clase, entonces dentro de la clase debes tener una función que tenga como parámetro la instancia.

```
 static setContadorPlayer1(obj) {
     obj.contadorPlayer1 = x; // x es una variable de clase
    }



    J1= new Player(..);

       J2=new Player(..);
        Player.setContadorPlayer1(J1); / cambia contadorPlayer1 en J1

        Player.setContadorPlayer1(J2); // cambia contadorPlayer1 en J2
```

Dentro del constructo: player.setContadoe(this)

Comment: Gracias. Lo que busco, es modificar el contador dentro de la propia clase, pero sin recurrir a la instanciación de la clase. 
Realmente no sé si es posible, me miraré la documentación. Tengo una función que selecciona el jugador activo, una vez seleccionado este, hay otra función que se encarga de mover al jugador y dentro de esa función llamo al contador cada vez que hay un movimiento, así de esa manera cuando hay un obstáculo, el contador no aumenta y el jugador activo no agota sus movimientos. Todo esto dentro de la clase.

Comment: Pero por la razón que sea, cuando desde el método contador quiero cambiarle el valor (resetear a 0) de contadorPlayer1, este no se modifica, sigue con el último valor dado por contadorPlayer++  con lo cual el segundo jugador continua activo de manera indefinida.

Comment: La verdad que es un poco difícil sin conocer el codigo de toda la clase o de los métodos que intevienen. Me parece que contadorPlayer1 no se resetea es porque no estas usando la instancia correcta. Ten presente que cuando se ejecuta el constructor se está creando otra instancia Player y estas pensando que es la misma en todo caso has un metodo  Init() con el mismo cuerpo del constructor y cuando quieras resetear le haces un jugador.Init(lista de parametro)

Comment: Gracias. El código es muy largo, pero voy a leer sobre el método que me comentas. También probaré lo que me dices de lo del constructor, puede que ahí este mi fallo. Gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Por si a alguien le ayuda dejo la solución.

Era más fácil de lo que creía. 
Tengo la siguiente clase.

```js
class Player{
  constructor(cutY, cutX, y, x){
  this.cutY = cutY
  this.cutX = cutX
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.gunsPoint
  this.contadorPlayer1 = 0
  this.contadorPlayer2 = 0
  }
```

La clase está instanciada con

```js
const player1 = new Player(0,32,player1Y,0)
const player2 = new Player(32,32,player2Y,14)
```

Algunos de los métodos de la clase son

```js
 obstacle(y,x){
          let colision = false
          let position = map.mapaGame[y][x]
          if(position == 1){
            colision = true
          }
          return colision
      }
      
          movement(direction, checkPosition, playerActive){
      switch (direction) {
        case up:
        if(this.y > 0)
        if(this.obstacle(this.y - 1, this.x) == false ){
          this.y--
          this.counter(playerActive)
          this.playerNext(checkPosition)
          this.getGuns()
        }
          break;

        case down:
          if(this.y < 9)
          if(this.obstacle(this.y + 1, this.x) == false){
            this.y++
            this.counter(playerActive)
            this.playerNext(checkPosition)
            this.getGuns()
          }
          break;

        case left:
          if(this.x > 0)
          if(this.obstacle(this.y, this.x - 1) == false){
            this.x--
            this.counter(playerActive)
            this.playerNext(checkPosition)
            this.getGuns()
          }   
          break;
        
        case right:
          if(this.x < 14)               
          if(this.obstacle(this.y, this.x + 1) == false) {
            this.x++
            this.counter(playerActive) 
            this.playerNext(checkPosition)
            this.getGuns()
          }       
          break;
      
        default:
          console.log('muro')
          break;
      }
    }//movement
```

Lo que nos interesa(porque hace referencia a lo que había preguntado)

Son los siguientes métodos.

```js
checkTurn() {
    if (this.contadorPlayer1 < 3) {
      this.activePlayer = true;
    } else if (this.contadorPlayer2 < 3) {
      this.activePlayer = false;
    } else {
      this.activePlayer = true;
    }

    return this.activePlayer;
  }

  reseteoPlayer2(nuevoNum) {
    this.contadorPlayer2 = nuevoNum;
  }

  reseteoPlayer1(nuevoNum) {
    this.contadorPlayer1 = nuevoNum;
  }

  counter(playerActive, contadorPlayer2, contadorPlayer1) {
    if (playerActive == 1) {
      this.contadorPlayer1++;
      if (this.contadorPlayer1 < 3) {
        console.log("Counter metodo Player 1: " + this.contadorPlayer1);
      } else if (this.contadorPlayer1 == 3) {
        player2.reseteoPlayer2(0);
        // this.contadorPlayer2 = 10
      }
    }

    if (playerActive == 2) {
      this.contadorPlayer2++;
      if (this.contadorPlayer2 < 3) {
        console.log("Counter metodo Player 2: " + this.contadorPlayer2);
      } else if (this.contadorPlayer2 == 3) {
        player1.reseteoPlayer1(0);
      }
    }
  }
```

El método checkTurn revisa qué jugador está activo. Siempre empieza el jugador 1. Para saber qué jugador está activo, lee siempre el `this.contadorPlayer1/2`y retorna true o false el cual es recogido/leído por un addEvenlis.... que se encarga de detectar las pulsaciones del teclado.

Una vez sabemos que jugador está activo, cada click mueve el jugador activo, llamando al método movement el cual mueve al jugador activo según la dirección dada, además revisa si hay un obstáculo, si el jugador contrario está cerca y si hay un arma.

pero vamos al lío. El método movement, le envía información al método counter que es quien se encarga de aumentar tanto en contador del jugador 1 como el contador del jugador 2 según quien de los dos esté activo. Así que es aquí en donde tenía que resetear los contadores de cada jugador para ponerlos a cero(sabía que era aquí pero no sabía cómo hacerlo :) )

Después de varias lecturas y sugerencias que me dieron aquí, conseguí resetear el contador de cada jugador dentro de la propia clase. Al final era hacerlo en 2 pasos (en total cuatro dos por cada jugador).

Primero crear un método que hiciera el reseteo para cada jugador y luego llamar dicho método desde el método counter utilizando para ello el objeto instanciado que en este caso era player1 y player2 y pasarle un parámetro.

Recapitulando. player1.reseteoPlayer1(0) Esto es para llamar a la función reseteoPlayer1 la cual accede al `this.contadorPlayer1/2` (o el 1 o el 2) y le da como valor el parámetro que le he enviado desde `player1.reseteoPlayer1(0)`

gracias @Aprendiz y @Juan Carlos Guibovich Tempest sin vuestras sugerencias esto no hubiera sido posible.

Comment: Me acerqué bastante connel metodo init :)

Answer (score 0):

Para sumarle valor númerico a una variable, se debe añadir el operador aritmético `++` o `--` para restar ya sea al final del valor o al principio

Algo así:

```
class Player{
  constructor(cutY, cutX, y, x){
  this.cutY = cutY
  this.cutX = cutX
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.gunsPoint
  this.contadorPlayer1 = 0
  this.contadorPlayer2 = 0
  this.dataPlayer
  this.dataCounter
  this.activePlayer
  }
  increment () {
  // suma
  this.contadorPlayer1 = this.contadorPlayer1++;
  }
  decrement () {
  // resta
  this.contadorPlayer1 = this.contadorPlayer1--;
  }
  print () {
    this.increment();
    console.log(this.contadorPlayer1);
  }
}
new Player().print();
```

También se puede de esta forma:

```
this.contadorPlayer1 = ++this.contadorPlayer1;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. No quiero incrementarlo de uno en uno quiero introducir directamente un valor x pero desde dentro dela propia clase, ya que ese contador lo utilizo para almacenar los movimientos de cada jugador.

Comment: Pues toma como ejemplo el ejemplo que te puse, o el de @Aprendiz que esta mejor explicado